# постраничная навигация PHP. Как улучшить?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. В самописном движке постраничная навигация реализована так

1. сначала считается все кол-во записей (select count)
2. Выбираются данные (select .....  limit   $openPage, 10 ) 
   Т.е все стандартно.

В базе 600 тыс. записей , из-за которых загрузка идет

1. без индексов 14 секунд
2. с индексами - 3 секунды

Подскажите, можно ли как-то сделать так , чтобы предварительно  считались не все записи, а к примеру 30 (на три страницы) ? Типа сделать limit Для count

Ну или другие ваши рекомендации  .
Спасибо

Comment: держите просто счетчик количества отдельной записью

Comment: а есть ли смысл держать его отдельно в базе , если у меня на сайте есть различные фильтры или категории ?

Comment: + попробуйте 2 запрос разбить на два: 1 часть - делаете `select id ...  limit $openPage, 10` (на поле id индекс), 2 часть - делаете `select * from ... where id in (список номеров из первой части)`

Comment: разбил по вашему совету, только не понял, что это может дать .. 
На практике - ничего не изменилось

Comment: в этом случае вам нужен поисковый движок вместо базы

Comment: Если в таблицу не надо много писать и транзакции, а надо много читать поменяйте движок с **InnoDB** на **MyISAM**. **MyISAM** хранит сколько записей в таблице поэтому `select count`  - "бесплатен". Скиньте `create` - длай таблицы и пару вариантов запросов. Может у вас индексы не правильные.